# .save() is not saving all the details given in list

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a list of size 20 which i am trying to save to database using .save() JPA.
but is saving only 17 rows.
After saving, i am checking in the database only 17 rows are getting reflected.

what might be the issue?

here is my code snippet.

```
List<MyBean> g=new ArrayList<>();
MyBean.add(mybean object);
MyBean.add(mybean object);
MyBean.add(mybean object);
MyBean.add(mybean object);
MyBean.add(mybean object);
MyBean.add(mybean object);
MyBean.add(mybean object); 
MyBean.add(mybean object);
MyBean.add(mybean object);
MyBean.add(mybean object);
MyBean.add(mybean object);
MyBean.add(mybean object);
MyBean.add(mybean object);
MyBean.add(mybean object);
MyBean.add(mybean object);
MyBean.add(mybean object);
MyBean.add(mybean object);
MyBean.add(mybean object);
MyBean.add(mybean object);
MyBean.add(mybean object);
repository.save(MyBean);
```

here it is saving only 17 rows in db, not all the 20.

Comment: Might be got updated due to duplicacy

Comment: I agree with @Sudhir, for further investigation you can see your database logs (If rows are being deleted there then it's definitely due to duplication)

Comment: You are correct @SudhirOjha, problem is because of duplicacy.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the soultion but a way to debug further

This is how List save implementation looks from inside.

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> List<S> save(Iterable<S> entities) {

    List<S> result = new ArrayList<S>();

    if (entities == null) {
        return result;
    }

    for (S entity : entities) {
        result.add(save(entity));
    }

    return result;
}
```

you notice its returning List. So all your persisted data are also returned.

you can cross check which entities are missing.